# How to set unicode in Livelin API using C#

Tags: api, c#-4.0, livelink

I am facing Encoding problem in LiveLink API, My code sample is

```
     _llsession = new LLSession(Server, Port, "", UserName, Password);
    _llsession.setEncoding("ISO-8859-6");
```

Could you please give information about what is default Encoding Livelink server use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set encoding in API. In order to set encoding method

Go to //Livelink/livelink.exe?func=admin.sysvars

Set charaset as UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You can check the default encoding in OpenText.ini inside config folder.